# LyX - How to lower ToC depth of multiple entries

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

Let's say I have a section with several entries:

1

1.1

1.2

But, I want to recategorize this section all into a subsection (and all of its subsections to become subsubsections, etc.) rather than a section, so that it becomes:

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.2

Is there a way to do this quickly in LyX? I have a huge document and I've been unable to find a way to do this except for manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question in case it helps anyone in the future, as I just learned how to do it. There's probably a better approach to go about it, but it works.

In your LyX toolbar (top of screen) click View > Outline Pane.

You should have a new pane open on the left side of your screen, listing the different sections in your document. On the bottom of this pane, there are buttons to "increase/decrease nesting depth", which increments/decrements the depth of an item and anything nested in it.